# Using EFCore with Identity for Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

For the last few days I've been fighting the Identity system in combination with Entity framework Core. Here's some information prior to revealing my problem:

1. Entity framework Core doesn't support lazy loading, this means that I'm using eager loading by saying which items to include
2. In order to say which items of an object I would like to retrieve I override a method in each repository ( the properties retrieved are constant for now )
3. The Identity system I'm using is configured as :

   ```
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
   {
       options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
   })  .AddUserManager<UserManager>()
       .AddRoleManager<RoleManager>()
       .AddUserStore<UserStore>()
       .AddRoleStore<RoleStore>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
   ```

Now on to the problem itself:

I would like to use the identity system in order to generate tokens, get users etc. but I cannot do eager loading on the `UserManager` object itself as it's methods return `Task<ApplicationUser>` and the `Include()` method itself requires `IQueryable` ( to do eager loading ). What is the general way to be both be able to use eager loading and `UserManager`?

Comment: You can following the issue at https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1082#issuecomment-273514725. I think it's good for resolving your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way maybe to call UserManger.Users directly. Like this:

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.Users.Include(s => s.Sales).Where(e => e.Email == "t@t.net").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use eager loading and UserManager as following:

```
    private async Task<ApplicationUser> GetSingleUser(Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>> 
         predicate, params Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<ApplicationUser> query = _userManager.Users;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return await query.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Hope this help!